# Elementwise subtraction of tensor values in one list

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor, elementwise-operations

I have a list `tensor_list` containing tensors in the form of matrices. Some of the matrices have a different shape (e.g. `torch.Size([512, 784]) and torch.Size([10, 512])`). I want to subtract each element from the element of the successor and store the result in a new list `tensor_deltas = []`. Since the list contains many tensors, I want to use a python loop. Here is a `tensor_list` example with two entries (normally there are much more):

```
[tensor([[-0.0262,  0.0310,  0.0067,  ..., -0.0162,  0.0241,  0.0181],
        [-0.0299,  0.0230, -0.0328,  ...,  0.0084, -0.0042, -0.0162],
        [ 0.0150,  0.0003, -0.0052,  ...,  0.0046,  0.0110,  0.0019],
        ...,
        [-0.0346, -0.0283,  0.0035,  ...,  0.0010,  0.0279, -0.0162],
        [-0.0166, -0.0165, -0.0339,  ..., -0.0101, -0.0346,  0.0035],
        [ 0.0146,  0.0320,  0.0009,  ...,  0.0065,  0.0058,  0.0288]]), tensor([[-6.2551e-03,  1.6126e-02,  3.9450e-02,  ...,  1.7971e-05,
          2.4612e-02, -4.0139e-02],
        [-3.0003e-02, -1.6719e-03, -2.3985e-02,  ...,  4.3558e-02,
         -1.9130e-02,  2.3564e-02],
        [ 2.9886e-02,  3.2086e-02, -4.1213e-02,  ..., -2.4083e-02,
          2.7199e-02, -4.3203e-02],
        ...,
        [ 2.7709e-02, -2.3003e-02,  4.4214e-03,  ...,  2.7394e-02,
         -1.6083e-02, -1.7070e-02],
        [ 3.7920e-02,  5.7346e-03, -2.7768e-02,  ...,  2.0152e-02,
          2.6525e-02, -1.8638e-02],
        [ 1.9585e-02, -5.5044e-03,  2.6463e-02,  ..., -3.2142e-02,
         -2.2696e-02,  1.6047e-02]])]
```

Specifically, I want to apply these operations `tensor_deltas.append(abs(-0.0262--6.2551e-03))`, `tensor_deltas.append(abs(0.0310-1.6126e-02))`, etc. to all elements of the tensors. How can I create an efficient loop for all tensors in the list? (Usually there are more than two tensors in the list.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you to happen at indices that are not present in all tensors? E.g. the first tensor has an element at index [11,0], but the second does not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Originally, I stored the tensors in a dictionary. To compensate the different shapes, I manually padded the smaller tensor with zeros using the command ``F.pad`` until it had the correct shape. Unfortunately, I cannot do this manually for 50 tensors. I thought it could be easier to have access to a list of tensors instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Specifically, I used this command to adjust the size of the smaller tensor to the larger one. ```weights_dict.update({'weights_1':F.pad(input=weights_dict['weights_1'], pad=(0,272,0,502), mode='constant', value=0)})```